# Bootstrap-timepicker delete first zero at values

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap-timepicker deletes the first zero at values, for example 09:30, and it turns out 9:30. It is necessary for me that it returned the correct values - if enter 0830 - 08:30 so further.

Github: http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/index.html

Help, how to solve a problem?

Comment: What is your format option set to during your timepicket initialization?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="bfh-timepicker" data-time="08:00">
</div>
```